# Javascript: Update the value of an Object fields

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following code:

```
var view = function () {

var formset_prefix = '', form_id = '';

var DOMStrings = {
    formset_total: 'TOTAL_FORMS',
    formset: '*[id$=-TOTAL_FORMS]',
    field: '*[id^=id_' + formset_prefix + '-]',
    field_idx = '*[id^=id_' + formset_prefix + form_id +'-]'

};

return {
....................
get_form_fields: function (prefix, id) {
            formset_prefix = prefix;
            form_id = id;
            console.log(formset_prefix);
            console.log(DOMStrings.field);
            return document.querySelectorAll(DOMStrings.field);
        }
..... }();
```

I don't know at the beginning what is the `formset_prefix` and `formset_id`, but I get them later using multiple function calls, so I initialize them at the beginning with empty.

Hoe can I force the update of the `DOMStrings` object attributes `field` and `formset` later when I update the `formset_prefix` and `formset_id values` ?

Comment: Make `DOMStrings` a function and compute the object on the fly.

Comment: so the object to be the return of the function ? the DOMString field attributes needs to be changed multiple times. Can you give me an example ? take in consideration that he has multiple values simple or computed.

Comment: Added an example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make `DOMStrings` a function and compute the object on the fly:

```
var formset_prefix = '', form_id = '';

var DOMStrings = function() {
    return {
       formset_total: 'TOTAL_FORMS',
       formset: '*[id$=-TOTAL_FORMS]',
       field: '*[id^=id_' + formset_prefix + '-]'
    }
}

return {
....................
get_form_fields: function (prefix, id) {
            formset_prefix = prefix;
            form_id = id;
            return document.querySelectorAll(DOMStrings().field);
        }
..... }();
```

Better yet, decouple it from the context, and pass necessary parameters as arguments:

```
var DOMStrings = function(prefix, id) {
    return {
       formset_total: 'TOTAL_FORMS',
       formset: '*[id$=-TOTAL_FORMS]',
       field: '*[id^=id_' + prefix + '-]'
    }
}

return {
....................
get_form_fields: function (prefix, id) {
            var strings = DOMStrings(prefix, id);
            return document.querySelectorAll(strings.field);
        }
..... }();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

The way you defined `view` - `formset_prefix`, `form_id`, `DOMStrings` are **private** for `view`. An option could be to create functions to set the values of `formset_prefix` and `form_id` that will take care to also update `DOMStrings`. For example:

```js
var view = function() {

  var formset_prefix = '',
      form_id = '';

  var DOMStrings = {
    formset_total: 'TOTAL_FORMS',
    formset: '*[id$=-TOTAL_FORMS]',
    field: '*[id^=id_' + formset_prefix + '-]'
  };

  return {
    /* .................... */
    get_form_fields: function(prefix, id) {
      console.log('formset_prefix = ' + formset_prefix);
      console.log('DOMStrings.field = ' + DOMStrings.field);
      return document.querySelectorAll(DOMStrings.field);
    },
    /* Setter for formset_prefix */
    set_formset_prefix: function(prefix) {
      formset_prefix = prefix;
      DOMStrings.field = '*[id^=id_' + formset_prefix + '-]';
      return this;
    },
    /* Setter for form_id */
    set_form_id: function(id) {
      form_id = id;
      return this;
    }
    /*.....*/
  }
}();


/* Note: when you return "this" you can chain the method calls
   and now you can do someting like the following
*/

var fields = view.set_formset_prefix('my-prefix')
                 .set_form_id('my-form-id')
                 .get_form_fields('my-prefix', 'my-form-id');
```